# How are control flow graphs built in cases where the jump destination is based on a dynamic environment value?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, control-flow-graph

In studying reverse engineering, it's frequently occurred to me that since I can pass any location (that I have permission to access) as the argument, a jump instruction with some non-hardcoded or "non deterministic" target (as in it's not defined previously by the program clearly) could aim anywhere. So if I load `EAX` with a value based on say, the string of the OS version and execute `jmp eax` then it seems like any tool attempting to generate a control flow graph would have no idea where the target would be (it could base it on your current environment, but that might lead to some broken pathway through the program).

Am I missing something? Because if I understood this correctly it seems like every malware I ever opened in IDA would do this (based on some condition they know about their target environment) but I don't see broken control flow graphs like this. Then again, I'm pretty new to reverse engineering.

Comment: Nitpick, there is no `Jcc EAX`.  All the conditional jump instructions take an immediate displacement.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah I was wondering if I messed that up. My learning of Assembly hasn't been very hands-on yet. ty.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in your observation.  There are two main ways to graph control flow for indirect jumps.

First, static analysis can be used.  For example, if the jump target is found to be selected from a jump table of limited length, the decompiler can list the entries of the jump table as possible targets.  Another common case is that the jump target is taken from a variable set elsewhere in the program, but always to the same value.  The decompiler can too analyse the possible values of the variable and deduce possible jump targets.

Another option is to build the control flow graph not from potential behaviour of the program, but from actual behaviour observed from a simulated or actual run of the code.  While this is likely to miss some possible control flow, it usually gives you a pretty decent picture of where jumps (including indirect jumps) usually go and allows for an explanation of the program's behaviour.

Comment: [Aha, so I handled it the right way :)](https://i.imgur.com/xzEs0fz.png)  (see very last entry at the bottom of diagram) I'm really [in over my head](https://www.reddit.com/r/lowlevel/comments/qtf7x7/looking_for_critiques_of_and_prior_research/) on this topic, not even being sure of details like this. I read most of the Intel Dev Manual for x86-64 but very little hands on experience with Assembly beyond hello world. Or even with a C lang... I was a JavaScript dev, how did I get here...

Comment: "or actual run of the code." that's also a point of curiosity for me. Obviously emulators struggle against evasion. So an actual run of the program in its intended environment is an interesting approach. When we run on bare metal, unless we modify the program, the register values are opaque to outside analysis, right? Even debugging APIs, if I understand correctly, leverage a feature on the x86 architecture allowing instructions to be flagged for breakpoints or something, so essentially we're patching the program to be able to utilize this, yes? (1/1)

Comment: @J.Todd Some debuggers can circumvent common anti-debugging strategies by e.g. emulating instructions that would make the debugger detectable (such as `pushf`).  But yes, it's difficult to get a correct execution trace in the face of such countermeasures.

Comment: (2/2) So then when it comes to doing this kind of analysis against a malicious program, that program can look at its own memory and see those modifications, and behave differently, yes? I wish there was a way to watch the instruction trace without the program fundamentally being able to know it's being watched. I think maybe JTAG can do something similar, but it's not a high enough frequency to query all the registers at every instruction executed, not even close.

Comment: You can use debug registers to set breakpoints without modifying the code.  But again you need a debugger that supports this.

Comment: can a user-mode program read those registers? If so, it can use that register state to deviate behavior and evade analysis of the malicious behavior. If not, then cool. Will definitely look into it.

Comment: @J.Todd A user mode program can do this as far as I know, but your debugger could just fake wrong values when such an attempt is made.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, as you already guessed, an instruction of the form `JMP EAX` could possibly jump anywhere and would therefore break the CFG of the program you are trying to reverse engineer (that is, you would not have exiting arcs to known pieces of code from the current basic block).

However, compilers rarely emit absolute indirect jumps. When they do they usually are for jump tables which are generated for `switch` statements. If we are talking about indirect *calls* (or jmp tail-calls), then we also have function pointers, and you see instructions of the form `CALL EAX` (very common in C++ i.e. [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)).  For `switch` statements for example, in order to correctly handle all possible values of its input variable or expression (e.g. an `int`), there usually is a little bit of code that makes sure the value is in a given range before using it to index an array of code pointers, and then an absolute indirect jump through a register (or more often `jmp [table + eax*4]`, maybe after doing some math on EAX).

The kind of idioms used and the compiler implementations (i.e. what machine code is generated) for this kind of situations are usually well known, so disassemblers and decompilers can detect them and figure out the input constraints plus the location of the jump table, and therefore the correct destinations (which is what IDA/HexRays does). Sometimes however this is not possible or simply too difficult for your disassembler/decompiler to figure out (e.g. the compiler used different unknown semantics, or the programmer purposely tried make reverse engineering harder).

Comment: "However, compilers rarely emit absolute indirect jumps."  Well, function pointers, and virtual methods.  Calls instead of jumps, I suppose, but same principle.

Comment: @NateEldredge yeah good point, added